# finding repeated sub string from sequence of string

Tags: r

I have a number of sequences of string. From each sequence I have to find all such sub string that repeats at least some minimum threshold time(th).

For example if one of the sequence of string is "aboaboaboaboaboabcabcabcabcab". If minimum repetition threshold(th=4) then substring of the particular sequence are "abo","boa","oab","abc","bca","cab".

I had solved it by brute force. But if we apply the method on at least 100000 such sequences then it take several minute in R. I want to find all such sub string in 100000 sequence in few seconds.

I would like to implement it in R.

Comment: I gather that the substring must be of length 3 - is this correct? Otherwise there are many strins of length 2 (or 1...) which meet this criteria.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `combn`, but it doesn't respect order as far as I can tell so comes up with far more combinations than are possible with order respected, e.g.,

```
s <- "aboaboaboaboaboabcabcabcabcab"
combos <- combn(strsplit(s, "")[[1]], 3, paste0, collapse="")
combos[1:5]
[1] "abo" "aba" "abb" "abo" "aba"
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work (assumes you want 3-letter substrings).

```
str <- "aboaboaboaboaboabcabcabcabcab"
th  <- 4

sub <- sapply(1:(nchar(str)-2),function(i)substr(str,i,i+2))
sub[which(table(sub)>=th)]
# [1] "abo" "boa" "oab" "abo" "boa" "oab"
```

And some benchmarking with a string of length 100,000.

```
get.repeats <- function(str,n,k){
  sub <- sapply(1:(nchar(str)-n+1),function(i)substr(str,i,i+n-1))
  sub[which(table(sub)>=k)]
}
# benchmark
set.seed(1)
str <- paste(sample(c("A","C","G","T"),1e5,replace=TRUE),collapse="")
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(get.repeats(str,3,4),times=10)
# Unit: seconds
#                    expr      min      lq   median       uq      max neval
#  get.repeats(str, 3, 4) 1.835401 1.86695 1.886206 1.917245 2.035076    10
```

So this runs in about 2 seconds.